# ambiguous D.I. constructors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out how D.I. work for my MAUI project because I got some errors.

My main goal here is to allow resolving new "services" (registered types in D.I.) with dynamics constructor's parameters at runtime.

So here is what i thought.

- Register the **transient/singleton** "services"/types I want to create (via my factories for information)
- Register **scoped** "services"/types for the constructors's parameters
- use `CreateScope` in my factories to call parametered constructors

But I doesn't work as I get `ambiguous ctor` errors using the builtin D.I.

Here is an example to illustrate it :

```cs
public interface IInterface { }
public interface IInterface1 : IInterface { }
public interface IInterface2 : IInterface { }
public interface IInterface3 : IInterface { }

public class CClass1 : IIinterface1 { }
public class CClass2 : IIinterface2 { }
public class CClass3 : IIinterface3 { }

public interface ITest
{
    IInterface I {get; init;}
}

public class Test
{
    IInterface I {get; init; }
    
    public Test(IInterface i) { I = i; }
    
    public Test(IInterface1 i1) : this(i1) { }

    public Test(IInterface2 i2) : this(i2) { }

    public Test(IInterface3 i3) : this(i3) { }
  }
```

The "services" configuration extract :

```
  //[...]
  mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();
  mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IInterface3, CClass3>();

  mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IInterface1, CClass1>();
  mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IInterface2, CClass2>();
  //[...]
```

My factory create methods example :

```cs
  ITest CreateTest1(IInterface1 i1)
  {
    using (var scope = App.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
      IInterface1 injectedI1 = i1;// how to properly inject it ? I thought it was automatic
      return App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>(); // ambiguous ctor error here
    }
  }

  ITest CreateTest2(IInterface2 i2)
  {
    using (var scope = App.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
      IInterface2 injectedI2 = i2;// how to properly inject it ? I thought it was automatic
      return App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>(); // ambiguous ctor error here
    }
  }

  ITest CreateTest3(IInterface3 i3)
  {
    using (var scope = App.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
      IInterface3 injectedI3 = i3;// how to properly inject it ? I thought it was automatic
      return App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>(); // ambiguous ctor error here
    }
  }
```

I use 3 `IInterface1/2/3` here because I tried to see what's hapened if 2 of them are registered with `AddScoped()` or a mix of `AddScoped()` and `AddTransient()` also.

So my thought that `using (var scope = App.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())` will somehow "force" D.I. to only use / seek constructors with parameters that are registered as `scoped` was wrong.

Either explaining me what goes behind so I can further investigate the issue and/or propose a solution to my goal (using parametered constructors dynamically at runtime via D.I. mechanism) would help. Thanks.

EDIT : Still investigating.

One thing first, correct mistake now I understand a little more scoped service :

```
  ITest CreateTest1(IInterface1 i1)
  {
    using (var scope = App.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
      //IInterface1 injectedI1 = i1;// how to properly inject it ? I thought it was automatic
      IInterface1 injectedI1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IInterface1>();
      injectedI1 = i1; //Meh ..
      //return App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>(); // ambiguous ctor error here
      return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>(); // still ambiguous ctor error here

    }
  }
```

And for constructor ambiguity, I'm reading [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/), especially :

> - Group 1: The container tries to prevent ambiguity by disallowing constructor resolution by default. If a type has multiple public constructors an exception is thrown.
> - Group 2: The container selects the constructor with the most parameters. If this constructor contains dependencies that cannot be resolved an exception is thrown.
> - Group 3: The container selects the constructor with the most parameters from the list of constructors where all of the parameters can be resolved by the container. When resolving a service, the container checks the configuration to see which dependencies can be resolved and selects the most appropriate constructor.

I suspect built in D.I. is type 3.
So in my example it found 3 constructor with 1 parameter, each one registered, so it cannot choose.

**I thought it would have been some signature Type checking, but maybe not ?**

Comment: For instance [Autofac](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/constructor-selection.html#iconstructorselector) by default chooses the constructor with the most (resolvable) parameters. I expect other DI containers to do the same. And when there is not 1 with *most* parameters (because all require 1), then it gives up

Comment: The [blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/) you referenced also explains why components should not have multiple injection constructors.

Comment: @Steven yeah after reading I'm again in a position of thinking "maybe I get it all wrong ?" (still doubting). Actually I though clever to implement all those overload constructor, like "I'm offering alternative convenient way to create a new object, it's better". But now I thought of deleting them and keep only my factory overloaded `Create` method. BUT in this case I'm back using `new` which whole D.I. concept is kinda get rid of it to decouple creation even more (? right ?)

Comment: I find it very difficult to give feedback on your design, because the code presented in your question is very abstract. My first knee-jerk reflect would be to keep `IInterface` out of the `Test` constructor because it presents a dynamic dependency. [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) is best for supplying classes with dependencies that can change per call. An injection method only *uses* an incoming dependency but *does not* store that dependency, which is opposite to constructor and property injection.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the build-in DI, you need either to use container which supports that (I think something can be done with [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html) for example) or to change your approach. Among the "change approach" options:

- remove the "injected" service from `ITest` implementation ctor parameter and just set it after creation:

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    IInterface I {get; set;}
}

// ...
var res = App.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest>();
res.I = i1; // i2, i3
```

- Use the factory pattern - i.e. you will create `ITestFactory` with `CreateTestX` methods and register it, and `Test` will be instantiated inside the methods (if you will need some other parameters for `Test` from DI - you can just create class `TestParameters`, register it in DI and inject it in your `ITestFactory` implementation so it will pass them to the `Test` ctor):

```cs
ITest CreateTest1(IInterface1 i1)
{
    IInterface1 injectedI1 = i1; 
    return new Test(i1); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you get a service using DI, one `Type` of service will have one implementation. You are not supposed to know anything about its dependencies or how the service implementation should be constructed.

However with the way you are defining `IIinterface1` through `IIinterface3` it looks like you actually want different implementations of `ITest` based on some other context.

Perhaps what you actually need is a generic type, perhaps with an open generic service description.

```cs
public interface IInterface{}

public interface ITest<TInt>
    where TInt : IInterface
{
    TInt I { get; }
}
public class Test<TInt>
    where TInt : IInterface
{
    public TInt I { get; }
    
    public Test(TInt i)
    {
      I = i;
    }
}
Services.AddScoped(typeof(ITest<>), typeof(Test<>));
```

Now you can register any service that extends `IInterface`, and then obtain an instance of `ITest` which can use that service.

```cs
public interface IInterface1 : IInterface {}
public class CClass1 : IIinterface1 {}
Services.AddScoped<IInterface1, CClass1>();

var test = ServiceProvider.GetService<ITest<IIinterface1>>();
```

This works because `typeof(ITest<IIinterface1>)` is a unique `Type` of service. With a unique implementation.